# How to send fax from android app?

Tags: android, fax

I wanted to implement fax sending in my android app. How can I do that? I searched lot about it but I didn't get any proper answer. Is there any API for fax sending from android app?

Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Android doesn't let you send FAX using it  SDK

But though you can perform this by using FAX APIS  like http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/php

Comment: As you mention is there any APIS like php FAX APIS. I search more about but didn't get any.

Comment: Its API service which is subject  to buy

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use an email-to-fax service, like www.greenfax.com, to send a fax from your android app.